# Set and get properties and constants differences

Tags: c#, syntax, properties, constants, readonly

Is there any difference between the following declarations (other than the difference between the `const` and `static readonly`)?

```
public static int foo1 { get; } = 8;

private static readonly int foo2 = 4;
public static int Foo2
{
    get { return foo2; }
}

private const int foo3 = 9;
public static int Foo3
{
    get { return foo3;}
}
```

What happens behind the scenes with `foo1`? is it the same as `foo2` or `foo3`?

I ask about `foo1` because I can't make it a `const` or `readonly` with this syntax, so I also ask if it's actually a constant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the same as `foo2`. The difference with `foo3` is that the property access won't even consult `foo3` - `Foo3` is compiled to code equivalent to

```
public static int Foo3
{
    { get { return 9; } }
}
```

Now admittedly from the perspective of *calling* code it really doesn't matter - in all cases you're exposing a property which will always return the same value.

If you want the equivalent of `Foo3` without the `const`, you could use:

```
public static int Foo4 => 10;
```

Comment: Okay now that I've calmed down, I see that `const` in C# is like an assembly label so it can't be used if you want to assign a value to it when instantiating the object. It's a little strange that with `foo1` the syntax isn't WYSIWYG (which C# really like compared to other languages).

Comment: @kuhaku: I'm afraid I really didn't follow your comment at all... but `foo1` is just a read-only automatically implemented property with an initial value of 9. The value could be changed in the constructor though.